# Compatibility between git clients

Tags: git, nfs

I'm using git in two different machines, the repo is on machine A that contains git `1.9.1`

On machine B I mounted the repo via NFS, amd the machine B contains git `2.7.4`

On machine A everything works fine but On machine B when I try to do `git fetch`  I get

```
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
fatal: loose object cdf74c69f4317b887e499fbabdf4d291807058ff (stored in .git/objects/cd/f74c69f4317b887e499fbabdf4d291807058ff) is corrupt
```

Note that no errors were reported by `git fsck --full` with `1.9.1`
and `2.7.4` instead tells me there are some bad references:

```
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
error: unable to unpack header of .git/objects/cd/f74c69f4317b887e499fbabdf4d291807058ff
error: cdf74c69f4317b887e499fbabdf4d291807058ff: object corrupt or missing: .git/objects/cd/f74c69f4317b887e499fbabdf4d291807058ff
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (235088/235088), done.
error: refs/heads/QA-5595: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

`git status` on Machine B shows deleted files as well.

Is there a known incompatibility between the two versions ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps git 1.9.1 doesn't detect the corruption, can you try `git cat-file -p cdf74c69f4317b887e499fbabdf4d291807058ff` in git 1.9.1 and tell us what it says?

Comment: Also try copying the whole repository over to the B machine, and not use it through NFS, see if that matters, make a copy using a zip file or something so that you know that you managed to get a complete non-corrupt copy, if NFS is somehow messing things up here a simple copy might not work either.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen : with 1.9.1 it shows the informations correctly

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I copied the repo on my B machine, and it seems working fine, it makes me think of this issue : https://about.gitlab.com/2018/11/14/how-we-spent-two-weeks-hunting-an-nfs-bug/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a `umount`/`mount` solved the problem. This makes me think of the issues that Gitlab had with NFS. I tried `ls` and `git gc` but I didn't work for me. for further reading check 
**How we spent two weeks hunting an NFS bug in the Linux kernel** : 
https://about.gitlab.com/2018/11/14/how-we-spent-two-weeks-hunting-an-nfs-bug/